# Handling password in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, passwords

How to not store password as plain text in jupyter notebook?

Using `input()` and `remove-output` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) standard library:

```
from getpass import getpass

pw = getpass('Input password: ')
```